# Find dynamic dictionary key values duplicates

Tags: python, dictionary

I am creating a dynamic dictionary like this:

```
a_list = ("Item1", "Item2", "Item3")
b_list = ("Item4", "Item5")
c_list = ("Item6", "Item7", "Item8", "Item9")

dct = {}

for x in range(100):

    dct['key_%s' % x] = []

    a = random.choice(a_list)
    dct['key_%s' % x].append(a)
    b = random.choice(b_list)
    dct['key_%s' % x].append(b)
    c = random.choice(c_list)
    dct['key_%s' % x].append(c)
```

where I populate each new key_ with a list of items **a, b, c** that get random values from **a_list, b_list, c_list**

Now I want to only have unique **a, b, c** values for each key in the **dct** dictionary so after finishing appending I would like to compare the last dictionary item to all of the previous ones and if a duplicate is found maybe remove that key pair and decrease the **x** so it will try adding another **a, b, c** value combination.

This is what I have also tried:

```
dct_values = list(dct.values())

if len(dct_values) > 1:
    last_item = list(dct.values())[-1]
    for allists in list(dct.values())[0:-1]:
        if last_item == allists:
            print(f"Duplicate found on {x} >> {last_item}")
            dct.popitem()
            x = x - 1
```

This will give me unique values but the key_# is not consecutive and the code looks *ugly*

The expected result is a dictionary with unique list key values from the a, b, c _list

Comment: If I understand you right, you don't want to have a list value where there are two same items next to each other?

Comment: Not necessary next to each other but no list duplicates anywhere in the key values of the dictionary

Comment: Are you sure you need a dict for this?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use generator that yield random unique items:

```py
import random


a_list = ("Item1", "Item2", "Item3")
b_list = ("Item4", "Item5")
c_list = ("Item6", "Item7", "Item8", "Item9")


def get_items(*lists):
    duplicates = set()
    while True:
        items = tuple(random.choice(l) for l in lists)
        if items not in duplicates:
            duplicates.add(items)
            yield items


dct = {
    f"key_{i}": items
    for i, items in zip(range(10), get_items(a_list, b_list, c_list))
}

print(dct)
```

Prints (for example):

```py
{
    "key_0": ("Item3", "Item4", "Item9"),
    "key_1": ("Item2", "Item5", "Item8"),
    "key_2": ("Item2", "Item4", "Item6"),
    "key_3": ("Item1", "Item4", "Item6"),
    "key_4": ("Item1", "Item5", "Item7"),
    "key_5": ("Item2", "Item5", "Item6"),
    "key_6": ("Item1", "Item5", "Item6"),
    "key_7": ("Item3", "Item4", "Item7"),
    "key_8": ("Item1", "Item5", "Item8"),
    "key_9": ("Item3", "Item5", "Item8"),
}
```